# Why does the word "Mars" shows up in google maps when viewing the Goldstone DSN complex?

Tags: mars, deep-space-network

In the Wikipedia page for the [Goldstone DSN complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_Deep_Space_Communications_Complex) there are coordinates. If you click them it takes you to GeoHack. I copies the decimal coordinates there `35.426667, -116.89` into my browser and it took me to the Goldstone complex.

Why does the map show a landmark labeled "Mars" next to one of the large dishes?

Is this an easter egg, or some name for the location?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is in the Wikipedia article:

> The DSS 14, "Mars" telescope

So it's the name for one of the antennas of the Goldstone complex.

Here are the [antennas](https://www.gdscc.nasa.gov/?page_id=40) and their names:

[image: Goldstone names]

Comment: Got it, nice graphic too. DSS-14 Goldstone's 70 meter dish, so Wikipedia either points to the center of the complex, or to the "main attraction". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've just run across this explanation of why this antenna in particular is named "Mars". From https://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/about/complexes/70-meter/

> NASA built the 70-meter antenna when ambitious missions began venturing beyond Earth orbit and needed more powerful communications tools to track them. The 70-meter antenna in Goldstone, dubbed the "Mars antenna," was the first of the giant antennas designed to receive weak signals and transmit very strong ones far out into space, featuring a 64-meter-wide (210-foot) dish when it became operational in 1966. The dish was upgraded from 64 meters to 70 meters in 1988 to enable the antenna to track NASA's Voyager 2 spacecraft as it encountered Neptune.
>
> While officially dubbed Deep Space Station 14, or DSS 14, the antenna picked up the Mars name from its first task: tracking the Mariner 4 spacecraft, which had been lost by smaller antennas after its historic flyby of Mars in 1965.