# What's the largest area dish antenna sent beyond the Earth-Moon system?

Tags: deep-space, deep-space-network, antenna, dish

In the same vein as the question [What's the largest aperture telescope sent beyond the Earth-Moon system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17008/12102), I'd like to ask, what's the largest area antenna dish sent beyond the Earth-Moon system?

If there's an array of dipoles that I don't know about that has a larger collecting area sent beyond the Earth-Moon system, that would be okay too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't made an exhaustive survey, but I checked the major outer-planets missions.

The [Galileo spacecraft was designed with a 4.6-meter diameter high-gain folding dish antenna](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraftDisplay.do?id=1989-084B) which was supposed to deploy somewhat like a folding umbrella; however, it jammed and didn't deploy fully, and the mission had to rely on a smaller antenna. I believe this is the biggest dish antenna flown to interplanetary space.

The runner-up and thus largest successful interplanetary dish would be [Cassini's 4-meter HGA](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/DPSummary/Descanso3--Cassini2.pdf).

Voyager 1 & 2's HGA dishes were 3.7 meters; Pioneers 10-11 2.74 meters; New Horizons 2.1 meters.

Russia/fUSSR and China don't seem to have attempted anything past Mars, and I'm assuming that inner-planet missions don't need such large dishes, but it's possible that I've overlooked something.

Comment: Over the last few years I've noticed your answers come faster and faster. I'm wondering if you've somehow finally managed to memorize *all of the space stuff?*

Comment: I believe Galileo's antenna was identical to those used on the original TDRSs, all of which worked OK. If only it hadn't had to sit around for so long..... https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/heo/scan/services/networks/tdrs_first_gen